# Drag and Drop to Move Original File and Create Copy in Current Folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer, file-management

**Summary**: I need a solution so that when I use Windows Explorer (or something similar) to drag and drop files, it actually moves the original file to the new location and creates a copy in the original location that is marked as read-only and hidden.

**Full Description**: I'm helping an organization (mostly on Windows 10/11) that needs to migrate and reorganize a large collection of documents on a file share to a new location.  Altogether they have many thousands of "client" files in thousands of directories with no consistent organization. They have created a template for how they want each client's folder and subfolders to be structured and will enlist all their users to manually migrate the files, so they are correctly sorted.

To keep things running smoothly during the transition period and as a safety measure, they don't want to remove or change anything in the original structure, but simply copying the files causes problems too.  They want the files in the new location to keep their original Created and Modified dates, plus they want an easy way to tell which files have already been migrated.

I'd like to implement a temporary solution, so that when they drag and drop from the current archive, it actually moves the file and creates a copy, with the properties read-only and also hidden (or maybe archive flag cleared).  For a bonus, it could also add a line to a text file in the current folder stating where the file was moved!

P.S. Simpler is better, so pie in the sky, (most of) this gets done with just Group Policy and registry keys. but PowerShell, a small app, or other solutions will be considered.

Comment: If you're copying to a new drive or partition, what you ask [as you've asked it] is impossible. Really this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - what you need is a copy mechanism that preserves the file dates.

Comment: Simpler idea : Keep a backup as a safety measure.

Comment: Is it fair to say that there currently aren't any known solutions for the problem that would consitute a good Answer on the SuperUser.SE?  If so, does it make sense to answer along these lines and then reformat the question for Stack Overlflow where the community could Answer with novel code to solve the problem?